# Can't get the code to change a shortcode based form in wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I am trying to do changes to a site register form but since it seems like I checked the theme whole files and searched exactly for the shortcode title too and didn't find anything at all...!

Here is the code of the page as :

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Create a FREE account &amp; save your Event date.</h1>
Whether you are Planning a Wedding, or any special event, you can save your search details here. Save pages and items of interest, communicate with vendors, save wish lists, and compare all of your options right here.

[row]
[column md="7"]
[couple-register-block title="Client Registration"]
[/column]
[column md="5"]
[iconbox icon="http://thegenius.co/wedding/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/envelop.png" layout="icon-box-main" title="Wedding Checklist" button_text="Help Center" button_url="#"]Nam poenatis condimentum. Fusce risus odiamrper at, lacinia vel leo.[/iconbox]
[iconbox icon="http://thegenius.co/wedding/demo/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/pricing.png" layout="icon-box-main" title="Useful Tools" button_text="View Now" button_url="#"]Venenatis conntum. Fusce risus odio, egestas sit amet ullamcornia vel leo.[/iconbox]
[/column]
[/row]
```

I want to get the form fields and change some fields in the form...The form shortcode is following in the above page as :

```
[couple-register-block title="Client Registration"]
```

I am just wondering where would I exactly get the form code for this shortcode in the theme files Cuz I searched the whole PHP files of the theme and didn't get any trace of it..!

Here is a live link of the page as : http://texaseventexperts.com/couple-login/couple-register/

What I want to do is to change the Wedding Date field to Event Date but I can't seem to find the code to change it and also the page is not using any custom template just the default template..!

Comment: Is that shortcode coming from a plugin (wedding-code)? If so, look in the appropriate plugin folder

Comment: @bamabacho : Yes...Exactly it's coming from that plugin..Can I know that how did you know about it?? Also I will accept it as answer if you post it as answer..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That short code is generated by the wedding plugin. If you navigate to the plugins folder, you will find it, and then look through to find where you might make necessary hacks. I used the console (developer tools or firebug, depending on your browser)to inspect the form element and look at "sources" to see what the site structure was that was being called to generate the page.